# how do I change or off in backend for uploading image default MAX WIDTH?

Tags: magento2, image-upload

In *Backend -> PRODUCTS -> CATALOG -> [any product] -> Images and Videos* when uploading images, Magento automatically makes resize(max-width 1920px). I need a image width 2600px. each product with self background. I created the Image-attribute: produkt_bg and show it on the product page. but the width is not enough.

How do I change this or turn it off in backend for uploading image default MAX WIDTH?

Comment: Hello Andrej and welcome to SE, would you please add more details to your question?

Comment: Backend -> PRODUCTS -> CATALOG -> [any product] -> Images and Videos.

when uploading images, Magento automatically makes resize(max-width 1920px).
I need a image width 2600px.

each product with self background.
I created the Image-attribute: produkt_bg and show it on the product page. but the width is not enough.

Comment: Hi @AndrejWasemiller could u please suggest on https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268126/magento-2-stop-or-avoid-resize-product-image-at-admin-end

Answer (score 1):

After **a lot** of digging in the code, I found that M2 resize the image *on the client*, that's it, before even uploading to the server.
This will be true if you use a browser that support Canvas and the File API.

To prevent this, you have to remove:

```
// vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/web/js/media-uploader.js:113
{
     action: 'resize',
     maxWidth: this.options.maxWidth,
     maxHeight: this.options.maxHeight
},
```

To be honest, I don't know exactly how to remove it in a clean way. The "easy way" would be remapping `Magento_Backend/js/media-uploader` to a custom js file and brutally copy/paste.

By the way, the above file is called here:
`vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/media/uploader.phtml`

Comment: @lazel could u please suggest on my post https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268126/magento-2-stop-or-avoid-resize-product-image-at-admin-end

Answer (score 0):

**Some clarification:**

The upload image size limitation is done in multiple area :

- Upload images on configurable product creation steps:

  `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/adminhtml/web/js/variations/steps/bulk.js:317`
- Upload image for a product

  `vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/media/uploader.phtml:17`
- Upload image for CMS

  `vendor/magento/module-cms/view/adminhtml/templates/browser/content/uploader.phtml:103`
- Abstract class with the constant value

  `vendor/magento/framework/File/Uploader.php:138`

To my mind Magento do not finish to implement correctly this feature because the value is harcoded for the configurable creation.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2.2.3 the max image sizes can be found in `/vendor/magento/framework/File/Uploader.php`

Comment: please advise on https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268126/magento-2-stop-or-avoid-resize-product-image-at-admin-end