# Magento 2 stop (or) avoid resize product image at admin end?

Tags: magento2, product, product-images, image-upload, image-resizing

In Magento 2.2.3 CE, Is it possible to get `default maximum image dimensions` in Magento when uploading images at admin end?

**For example**,

I uploaded some images to a product that were `2400x2400` and `1800x1800`, but they were resized to `1200x1200` on the product page.

**I would like to keep the original image sizes because I need higher resolution on some product images to show greater detail.**

[image]

Magento Admin end while upload:

[image]

Comment: You want this for your custom module or for core functionality ?

Comment: let me know do u have any free module?

Comment: It might be help https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84772/magento-2-keep-product-image-aspect-ratio

Comment: You can control the image dimensions and size in app/design/theme-directory/etc/view.xml file

Comment: @here i have updated my post please review and suggest me thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can set default image upload size in your **Magento Admin images upload system configuration**:

> **Stores→Configuration→Advanced→System→Images Upload Configuration**

From there you can set the **image upload** **Maximum Height** and **Maximum Width**

Comment: are u using EE?

Comment: Magento CE 2.3.0

Comment: ok got it, hello @magefms i am using 2.2.3CE the above feature not available.  any way thanks for the infomation

Answer (score 0):

- If we want to achieve we have to override `vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/web/js/media-uploader.js` from our custom module.
- Create a module for example: `Kensium_Uploadimage`.
- Create **requirejs-config.js** `app/code/Kensium/Uploadimage/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js` & override `media-uploader.js` following below

  ```
   /**
   *
   * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
   * See COPYING.txt for license details.
   */

   var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
          "Magento_Backend/js/media-uploader": "Kensium_Uploadimage/js/media-uploader"
        }
      } 
  }
  ```
- Create `media-uploader.js` in the following path `app/code/Kensium/Uploadimage/view/adminhtml/web/js/media-uploader.js`

  ```
   /**
   *
   * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
   * See COPYING.txt for license details.
   */
   /**
   * @api
  */

  /*global byteConvert*/


   define([
      'jquery',
      'mage/template',
      'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert',
       'mage/translate',
      'jquery/file-uploader'
     ], function ($, mageTemplate, alert) {
     'use strict';

     $.widget('mage.mediaUploader', {

      /**
       *
       * @private
       */
      _create: function () {
          var
              self = this,
              progressTmpl = mageTemplate('[data-template="uploader"]');

          this.element.find('input[type=file]').fileupload({
              dataType: 'json',
              formData: {
                  'form_key': window.FORM_KEY
              },
              dropZone: '[data-tab-panel=image-management]',
              sequentialUploads: true,
              acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
              maxFileSize: this.options.maxFileSize,

              /**
               * @param {Object} e
               * @param {Object} data
               */
              add: function (e, data) {
                  var
                      fileSize,
                      tmpl;

                  $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                      fileSize = typeof file.size == 'undefined' ?
                          $.mage.__('We could not detect a size.') :
                          byteConvert(file.size);

                      data.fileId = Math.random().toString(33).substr(2, 18);

                      tmpl = progressTmpl({
                          data: {
                              name: file.name,
                              size: fileSize,
                              id: data.fileId
                          }
                      });

                      $(tmpl).appendTo(self.element);
                  });

                  $(this).fileupload('process', data).done(function () {
                      data.submit();
                  });
              },

              /**
               * @param {Object} e
               * @param {Object} data
               */
              done: function (e, data) {
                  if (data.result && !data.result.error) {
                      self.element.trigger('addItem', data.result);
                  } else {
                      alert({
                          content: $.mage.__('We don\'t recognize or support this file extension type.')
                      });
                  }
                  self.element.find('#' + data.fileId).remove();
              },

              /**
               * @param {Object} e
               * @param {Object} data
               */
              progress: function (e, data) {
                  var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10),
                      progressSelector = '#' + data.fileId + ' .progressbar-container .progressbar';

                  self.element.find(progressSelector).css('width', progress + '%');
              },

              /**
               * @param {Object} e
               * @param {Object} data
               */
              fail: function (e, data) {
                  var progressSelector = '#' + data.fileId;

                  self.element.find(progressSelector).removeClass('upload-progress').addClass('upload-failure')
                      .delay(2000)
                      .hide('highlight')
                      .remove();
              }
          });

          this.element.find('input[type=file]').fileupload('option', {
              process: [{
                  action: 'load',
                  fileTypes: /^image\/(gif|jpeg|png)$/
              },  {
                  action: 'save'
              }]
          });
      }
  });

  return $.mage.mediaUploader;
   });
  ```
- only difference is below code removed from custom module.

  ```
   {
   action: 'resize',
   maxWidth: this.options.maxWidth,
   maxHeight: this.options.maxHeight
  }
  ```
- One more important note is `Magento 2.3.1 Release Notes this issue seems to be addressed`.

  You can now upload PDP images larger than 1920 x 1200 without compressing and downsizing the images first. Previously, when a merchant uploaded a high quality product image (larger than 1920X1200), Magento resized and compressed the image. Merchants can now set requirements for resizing and compression as well as compression quality and target width and height.

[image]